# Fork Jekyll on Gitlab not working - showing 404 for pages

Tags: gitlab, jekyll

I am creating a new project template using Jekyll by doing > new project template > choose Jekyll.

However, when I run the CI/CD build to serve the pages

- the CSS pages are kinda messed up
- When I click on the Jekyll post it shows a 404 like below.

There aren't any further instructions in the site: I have already removed the fork relationship and enabled runners as per instructed. https://gitlab.com/pages/jekyll

Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are correctly setting up `url` and `baseurl` configs in the `_config.yml` file.

The `url` refers to the domain name with schema prefix. For example: `https://example.com`.

The `baseurl` refers to the sub-path from where your site should be served. It should start with `/`. For example: `/blog`, `/docs`, etc.

**_config.yml**

```yaml
# other config
url: "https://example.com"
baseurl: "/blog"
# other config
```

This lets the theme know where you want to serve the site from. In this case it becomes `https://example.com/blog`.

But if you are using a custom theme, you need to make sure you do certain fixes.

For example, if you are referencing assets without using baseurl and url you need to fix it.

```html
<script src="/assets/js/theme.js"></script>
```

should become

```html
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/js/theme.js"></script>
```

to utilise the `baseurl` property if the sub-path changes.

Similarly, `<link>` in `<head>`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/theme.css">
```

becomes

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/theme.css">
```

This worked for me while moving a site hosted on a root domain at GitHub, to a test GitLab environment on a sub-path.

If you use a theme from the marketplace then this thing could already be configured and you can go ahead just with `url` and `baseurl` config in `_config.yml`.